# Whats wrong with this Oracle CTL File or data?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, sql-loader

My data is this:

```
ID,SCORE_DATE,TYPE,SCORE,RAW_SCORE,RANK
A1234,2012-09-05 23:59:59,FOOTBALL_TEAM_MIDDLE_AND_OLD_1234,10,0.123,1
A5678,2012-09-05 23:59:59,FOOTBALL_TEAM_MIDDLE_AND_OLD_1234,20,0.456,2
```

CTL FILE:

```
load data           
infile 'E:\Data\Sample.csv'
badfile 'E:\Data\Sample.bad'
APPEND into table TABLE1    
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS               
(   
 DRIVER,
 STARTDTE "to_date(SUBSTR(:STARTDTE,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 27",
 TYPE  CONSTANT 'FOOTBALL',
 SCORE   ,
 RANKSCORE ":SCORE",
 RANK    ,
 ENDDTE "to_date(SUBSTR(:STARTDTE,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')",
 LOADDT     "sysdate"
)
```

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE1"
  (
    "DRIVER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    "STARTDTE" DATE,
    "SCORE"           NUMBER,
    "ENDDTE" DATE,
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "RANK"       NUMBER,
    "RANKSCORE"  NUMBER,
    "LOADDT"     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  );
```

I am getting an error message for every row loaded:
Record 3: Rejected - Error on table TABLE1, column SCORE.
ORA-01722: invalid number

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. TYPE is an oracle keyword, you are better off not using such column names.
2. There is no TYPE column in your table definition . If the column exists, move the constant assignment to the end of the control file, after all the fields have been read.

   STARTDTE "to_date(SUBSTR(:STARTDTE,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 27",
    **TYPE  CONSTANT 'FOOTBALL',**
    SCORE   ,

And if you are trying to ignore the field that has "FOOTBALL_TEAM_MIDDLE_AND_OLD_1234" as data, you'll need to add

```
THIRD_COLUMN FILLER,
```

to your control file to ignore that data. Something like..

```
load data           
infile 'E:\Data\Sample.csv'
badfile 'E:\Data\Sample.bad'
APPEND into table TABLE1    
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS               
(   
 DRIVER,
 STARTDTE "to_date(SUBSTR(:STARTDTE,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 27",
 THIRD_COLUMN FILLER,
 SCORE   ,
 RANKSCORE ":SCORE",
 RANK    ,
 ENDDTE "to_date(SUBSTR(:STARTDTE,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')",
 LOADDT     "sysdate"
 TYPE  CONSTANT 'FOOTBALL',
)
```

should fix the errors you are getting.

Comment: Rajesh-Sorry that was a typo, there is a TYPE column in the table. Can you explain the "FILLER1 FILLER" part a little more please? I want a constant 'FOOTBALL' inserted instead of the value coming in the data file.

Comment: If you want to ignore the third  column from your file, you need to specify that the column be ignored. That can be done using the keyword "FILLER". Edited my answer.

Comment: Rajesh, the third column is TYPE. I just want to ignore the data I get in my data file and insert 'FOOTBALL' instead.THIRD_COLUMN is not a separate column than TYPE.

Comment: I have TYPE FILLER and then TYPE  CONSTANT 'FOOTBALL',I get an error SQL*Loader-404: Column TYPE present more than once in TABLE1's INTO TABLE block.

Comment: I can still use FILLER to load the data and then run a sql script to UPDATE those records. I wanted to know if I can do that using just the CTL file.

Comment: Ram - there is no need to update after the load. The thing is, you cannot specify "Ignore the third field and use this constant instead" in a single line in your control file. As sqlloader reads through the file, you ask it to ignore the third field. and at the end, tell it to load the type column with a new constant.

Comment: TYPE FILLER and then TYPE CONSTANT 'FOOTBALL' will obviously error out. you need to ignore the third field in your control file, so that should be "DUMMY_COLUMN filler" or "third_column filler" or "filler1 filler". The actual column, that you are populating at the end should have the correct column name.